# How to position image fixed to windows top when scrolled

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm trying to position an image to the top of the window, but having the scroll position calculated so the image which has `position: fixed;` always stays on top and visible no matter if you're scrolling or not. How can i do that? I want to use gsap to animate it to its position.

Here's my current code:

html:

```
<img id="image" src="image.jpg">
```

JS:

```
function toggleState(event) {
  if(event) {
    const img = event.currentTarget;

    const rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    const st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
    const sl = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft || 0;
    const ct = document.documentElement.clientTop || document.body.clientTop || 0;
    const cl = document.documentElement.clientLeft || document.body.clientLeft || 0;

    const top = Math.round(rect.top + st - ct);
    const left = Math.round(rect.left + sl - cl);

    gsap.to(img, {
      //what to do?
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `position: sticky` instead? You don't need JS for this.

Comment: In this case, i do.

Answer (score 0):

Doh. This is how you do it..

```
const top = window.pageYOffset;
const left = 0;

gsap.to(img, {
  top: top,
  left: left,
  duration: 1,
  easing: "linear"
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).